# Regex match when a string exists OR a string does not exist

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match when a string exists OR a string does not exist
In the following :

```
username test privilege 10 secret 0
username cisc privilege 15 password secret
username cisco privilege 10 secret
```

I need to find any "username cisco" instances and match, OR match if no "username" exists at all. This is because our router/switch config files either ship with cisco as default or no username at all.

So far I have tried:

```
(?s)u\w{7} cisco|^((?!u\w{7}).)*$

(?s)(u\w{7}) cisco|^[^username]$

(?s)(u\w{7}) cisco|^[^\1]$
```

the regex after "|" evaluates to "no match". I need it to match (in my case a match will be a fail) if no "username" exists. I have a feeling it is some sort of lookbehind or lookaround fix, but I can't get the syntax correct.

Thanks in advance

Working on it here: https://regex101.com/r/PpDj3y/7

Comment: You can use: [`^(?!.*username).+|username cisco`](https://regex101.com/r/PpDj3y/8)

Comment: Genius, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex with an alternation and a negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!.*username).+|username cisco/m
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^` - Start
- `(?!.*username)>_` is a negative lookahead to assert failure if line contains 
  `username`, thus matching a line without `username` anywhere.
- `|` - OR
- `username cisco` - Match literal text `username cisco`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PpDj3y/8)